# Install Ubuntu from another debian linux desktop?

Tags: system-installation

I have a system with Zorin os and the USB port doesn't work. how can i install ubuntu? can i run the installation from zorin desktop?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: You can use [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) with Ubuntu. However, it's not a trivial process, nor regularly tested. You may encounter unexpected pain points along the way. Ubuntu is not designed to run on (not to compensate for) broken or faulty hardware, so you are rather blazing your own trail.

Comment: Does the machine have a DVD drive? Make a Live Media DVD

Comment: I've used laptops for QA-test purposes that didn't have working *bootable* USB ports, where I'd update the ISO on the laptop drive using network & an OS on the machine I'd not replace (*Debian I think actually*); then a script would scan & update the grub config for the ISOs I'd put there to test so they'd appear as boot options, and I'd do my QA-test installs using other portions of the disk or just use ISO s *live* media, so yes it's possible... but it's more work than bootable media.. I wrote an answer on how to do that so details exist on this site (ie. *booting ISO using grub*)

Comment: If you create a small FAT32 partition on your hard drive, say about 5 GB, You can extract the Ubuntu ISO to it and let UEFI boot Ubuntu without needing to mess with GRUB. 

You may need to choose the option by pressing F9, F10, F12, or what ever combination your computer uses to select boot disk.